# How to rewrite this multiprocessing code for Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, windows, multiprocessing

I'm currently using multiprocessing so I can obtain user input while running other code. This version of code runs on ubuntu 19.04 for me, but for my friend it doesn't work on windows.

```
import getch
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

prev_user_input = ' '
user_input = ' '


# Getting input from the user
queue = Queue(1)

def get_input():
    char = ' '
    while char != 'x':
        char = getch.getch()
        queue.put(char)

# Starting the process that gets user input
proc = Process(target=get_input)
proc.start()


while True:

    # Getting the users last input
    while not queue.empty():
        user_input = queue.get()

    # Only print user_input if it changes
    if prev_user_input != user_input:
        print(user_input)
        prev_user_input = user_input

    time.sleep(1/10)
```

How can I make this code work on windows?

Also the user input lags behind by one input. If the user presses a button it only prints after he pushes another button. Solutions on how to fix this would also help.

Edit 1:
He's using Python 3.7.4 and I'm using 3.7.3.

I tried this code as suggested

```
import msvcrt
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

prev_user_input = ' '
user_input = ' '


# Getting input from the user
queue = Queue(1)

def get_input():
    char = ' '
    while char != 'x':
        char = msvcrt.getch()
        queue.put(char)

# Starting the process that gets user input
if __name__ == '__main__':
    proc = Process(target=get_input)
    proc.start()


    while True:

        # Getting the users last input
        while not queue.empty():
            user_input = queue.get()

        # Only print user_input if it changes
        if prev_user_input != user_input:
            print(user_input)
            prev_user_input = user_input

        time.sleep(1/10)
```

But no characters were printed.

Edit 2:
I'm using [`msvcrt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html#module-msvcrt) module on windows and the [`getch`](https://pypi.org/project/getch/) module on ubuntu. Sorry for not making that clear earlier in the post.

Comment: Try adding an `if __name__ == '__main__':` line before the `# Starting the process that gets user input` line — also indent that line all the code following it, as well. The need for this is explained in [Programming Guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming) for the `multiprocessing` module in the "Safe importing of main module" sub-section.

Comment: Which versions of python are you using on each machine?

Comment: @martineau I tried doing that. Now the program doesn't crash but it doesn't display the same behaviour that it did in linux which is the printing of characters.

Comment: @AnnKilzer I'm using 3.7.3 and he's using 3.7.4.

Comment: I don't understand how using `msvcrt.getch()` could have worked on anything other than Windows — yet you claim it does on ubuntu.

Comment: @martineau I should've made that clear. I was using msvcrt on windows and getch on ubuntu. Originally it was just getch in the post, but since I realised that doesn't work on windows I changed it. So sorry about that.

Comment: OK. I now think the problem is that there's two `Queue`s, one in each process. Processes run in separate memory-spaces, there's no sharing of global variables. You need create one in the  `__main__` process and pass it as an argument to `get_input()` target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me on Windows. It incorporates all the changes I suggested in my comments under your question, including the final one about separate memory-spaces.

Something similar should also work under ubuntu using its version of `getch()`, although I haven't tested it. on The main process creates the `Queue` and passes it as an argument to the `get_input()` target function so they're both using the same object to exchange data.

I also `decode()` the [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects) object returned from `msvcrt.getch()` to convert it into a (1 character) Unicode UTF-8 string.

```
import msvcrt
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

prev_user_input = ' '
user_input = ' '


def get_input(queue):
    char = ' '
    while char != b'x':
        char = msvcrt.getch()
        queue.put(char.decode())  # Convert to utf-8 string.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Getting input from the user.
    queue = Queue(1)

    # Starting the process that gets user input.
    proc = Process(target=get_input, args=(queue,))
    proc.start()


    while True:

        # Getting the users last input
        while not queue.empty():
            user_input = queue.get()

        # Only print user_input if it changes
        if prev_user_input != user_input:
            print(user_input)
            prev_user_input = user_input

        time.sleep(1/10)
```

#### Update

To hide the OS differences and make the code more portable, you could do the `import`ing as shown below, which would also allow you to define the `get_input()` function more like you did in the code in your question:

```
import os
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

try:
    import msvcrt
    getch = msvcrt.getwch  # Wide char variant of getch() that returns Unicode.
except ModuleNotFoundError:  # Not Windows OS - no msvcrt.
    from getch import getch

prev_user_input = ' '
user_input = ' '


def get_input(queue):
    char = ' '
    while char != 'x':
        char = getch()
        queue.put(char)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # For getting input from the user.
    queue = Queue(1)

    # Starting the process that gets user input.

    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: This solution worked, thank you so much. What is the point of the b before 'x'? Also why is it that when using char.decode() there isn't any lag in printing characters bu there is when not using it? Also char.decode() works flawlessly on windows, but on ubuntu I get an error. `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'` Why is that?

Comment: The `b` string prefix indicates the literal is an instance of the built-in [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects) class, which is the type of value `msvcrt.getch()` returns. The `decode()` call converts that to a regular Python string which are utf-8 Unicode encoded. None of that would be necessary if you used [`msvcrt.getwch()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.getwch) — the "wide" char variant of `getch()` — instead, because it returns Unicode. Apparently the `getch()` on ubuntu returns utf-8 strings, so it also doesn't need to do this.